# Getting 404 on landing page for Octopress on Github

Tags: osx-mavericks, octopress, github-pages

I followed Octopress original documentation and this [blog](http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/) to setup on Github pages. However once I deploy it and go to my [blog url](http://aniruddhab.github.io) I'm getting 404.

I verified the setup by running it locally on port 4000 and it's fine. Would appreciate any help to make it work. Following is the [link for the source file](https://github.com/aniruddhabarapatre/aniruddhab.github.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you GitHub page at https://github.com/aniruddhabarapatre.

So your GitHub pages should be at http://aniruddhabarapatre.github.io/, not http://aniruddhab.github.io/.

The [article](http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/) you reference does mention:

> Create a new GitHub repository. If you are creating a personal blog create a repo called:

```
username.github.com
```

With '`username`' being your GitHub account username (here `aniruddhabarapatre`).

---

[Project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages) (mentioned by [Joel Glovier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185973/joel-glovier) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002117/getting-404-on-landing-page-for-octopress-on-github/23004740#comment35171604_23004740)) is a good fit for your case, allowing you to:

- define a `gh-pages` branch in your https://github.com/aniruddhabarapatre/aniruddhab.github.io repo
- find the content of that branch published in http://aniruddhabarapatre.github.io/aniruddhab.github.io (meaning you might want to change the name of that `aniruddhab.github.io` repo)

But the idea remains: you already have one [User Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages). You cannot define a second one with the same account. Only project pages (one main page per project).

Comment: I already have another blog (Jekyllbootstrap) set up at `username.github.com`, hence I pushed it to another repository location. Can't I have multiple blogs on Github pages

Comment: @Aniruddha no, that was my point: it is based on the GitHub username. You can define sub-domain within your http://aniruddhabarapatre.github.io/, or you can create another user account.

Comment: Gotcha. I will try this tonight and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a gh-pages branch on any repository to host and then access through http://username.github.com/repo_name

Comment: @JoelGlovier True: **project pages** (https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages): those are the "subdomains" I was alluding to in `username.github.io`.